# Error in layout name?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

Iam using Jellybean. When i was putting layout name, this layout name is automatically created same as menu name. Then i access layout for main activity, i can't access id. I got error with main cannot resolved variable.
Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_first);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_first, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Some code would help :) Are you using the + before the id?

Comment: menu and layout name same. activity_my_first..So i created textview id inside layout file. But when i create resource inside oncreate i got error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently ran into this problem as well.
It turned out that the generated name "activity_main" was not accepted. I removed the underscore and it worked.  After I removed the _ underscore   it was able to generate the R file.

Incidentally  this was an error right from the originally generated code.
I had never seen this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project!

**Project - > Clean**

Select "**Build Automatically**" so that every time you clean the project, it will be rebuilt. And yeah, make sure you are saving the file before cleaning it (I know it is weird but sometimes the errors refuse to go away until you save it and then Clean it). Make sure that there is **no error** in the files in the **layout folder**, as it sometimes prevents the auto-generation of the code in R.java

Also, make sure that your code in MainActivity.java does not have **`import android.R`**. Eclipse tends to add that when you are managing the imports.

Comment: Added a few more possibilities in my updated answer. Hope they help.